# Dark mode does not work globally in components in React Native using NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm still struggling with an error that I can't figure out.
I did not find clear information on how to solve it (only information on how to put the color on a single component)
In their documentation it says that you have to override in a config and set the theme to dark, but it works for me..

My App.tsx

```
const config: object = {
        useSystemColorMode: false,
        initialColorMode: 'dark',
    };

    // extend the theme
    const customTheme = extendTheme({ config });

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
              <NativeBaseProvider theme={customTheme}>
                <Navigator />
              </NativeBaseProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
```

And now if I go to another screen where I create a new component with `<View></View>` it's still white..